# How did I get this badge

Tags: discussion

I recently got a badge fro Javascript, the requirement of which says

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki
>   answers in the javascript tag

But I have never posted a non-community wiki answer.

How did I get this badge?

UPDATE

I have confused with community wiki and non-community wiki answers. The question had come out of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A random selection of 5 posts I happened to look at on your profile were all non-community wiki answers, so clearly you have in fact posted answers that aren't community wikis.  I'm too lazy to do the rigorous search to look, but given your question I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you haven't posted any community wiki answers at all, so *all* of your answers are non-community wiki answers.

So to answer your question, you got the badge because you earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the javascript tag.

Comment: Of course. I have confused community wiki and non-community wiki. Thanks.